# Testing React application with Jest with envalid library throws error: process.exit called with "1"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, environment-variables

I am trying to test out my React/Typescript application with Jest and i get this error. I am using `envalid` library to have my env variables with types and autocompletion:

```
 const ENV = cleanEnv(process.env, {
        |             ^
      6 |   REACT_SOME_VALUE: str({ default: 'someValue' }),

 at defaultReporter (node_modules/envalid/src/reporter.ts:62:3)
      at Object.getSanitizedEnv (node_modules/envalid/src/core.ts:100:3)
      at cleanEnv (node_modules/envalid/src/envalid.ts:18:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/environment.ts:4:13)

process.exit called with "1"
```

Code where I define environments:

```js
import { cleanEnv, str } from 'envalid';

const ENV = cleanEnv(process.env, {
  REACT_SOME_VALUE: str({ default: 'someValue' }),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE1: str(),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE2: str(),
});

export default ENV;
```

Test that i am failing is a simple render test for my App component:

**App.test.tsx**

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import App from './app';

describe('App tests', () => {
  it('Should render without errors', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render(<App />);
    });
  });
});
```

*NOTE

This code works in runtime and does not throw error in compile time, but it throws error when i run Jest test.

Comment: Got a similar issue and it turned out that `dotenv` didn't load the env file because of the wrong path. That one environmental variable that caused the issue wasn't used at runtime that's why it didn't error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem was a bit strange, since runtime and compile time didn't throw errors.

Methods that `envalid` provide for returning typed values cannot be without `default` value.

So, in this case `str()` cannot be without `default` value. That is the main cause of this error.

To solve this, i just added empty string as default value and that is it:

```js
import { cleanEnv, str } from 'envalid';

const ENV = cleanEnv(process.env, {
  REACT_SOME_VALUE: str({ default: 'someValue' }),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE1: str({ default: '' }),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE2: str({ default: '' }),
});

export default ENV;
```

Comment: This is wrong. It is clearly valid to use `str()` without a default as can be seen in the envalid docs. Providing a default fixes the error in your tests but introduces a more serious problem: now envalid won't show an error at startup if your config values are missing in production.

Comment: Good catch. This is a short sighted solution for sure. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this, without affecting env variables validation in production, is to use the `devDefault` property along with the function `testOnly`.

For example:

```
import { cleanEnv, str, testOnly } from 'envalid';

const ENV = cleanEnv(process.env, {
  REACT_SOME_VALUE: str({ devDefault: testOnly('someValue') }),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE1: str({ devDefault: testOnly('') }),
  REACT_APP_OTHER_VALUE2: str({ devDefault: testOnly('') }),
});

export default ENV;
```

You can find this in [envalid's documentation](https://github.com/af/envalid#testonly).

Comment: Good catch Lusi. This is the one that can solve the issues of non existing value in test mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some or all of your required env vars are not defined in your Jest environment. It's confusing because Jest conceals the pretty error message that envalid normally shows and all you get is the cryptic `process.exit called with "1"`.

You can define a `.env.test` or similar but you need to explicitly load it, either in your test file or – better – in a global setup file:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env.test` });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround for the problem that jest swallows the `console.error`  message. It is not very beautiful but works with adding a modified reporter:

```
cleanEnv(
  process.env,
  {
    // your env definition here
  },
  {
    reporter: ({ errors, env }) => {
      defaultReporter(
        { errors, env },
        {
          onError: () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              process.exit(1);
            }, 0);
            throw new TypeError('Environment validation failed');
          },
          logger: console.error.bind(console),
        },
      );
    },
  }
)
```

The `setTimeout` does the magic so that you can see the envalid error-message on the console again.